# Why on a wire with delay, sharp voltage change at one end will not be observed at the other end

Tags: verilog, circuit

When I was writing some Verilog code, I found something really confusing.

I defined a wire whose delay is 20ns. The module is as follows:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module wireDelay(
    input a_i,
    output b_o
);

wire #20 w_tmp;

assign w_tmp = a_i;
assign b_o = w_tmp;

endmodule
```

And during the simulation, I found that if the electrical level of input doesn't stay for some time longer than wire delay, it wouldn't be observed on the output side.

[image]

The wave above is input while the other is output.

I am wonder why it happens and whether it's true in the real world?

Comment: The net declaration delay is used to model actual delay in a combinational circuit. Here, `w_tmp` is simply a *20ns* delayed version of `a_i`. If you have a lot of combinational logic with many gates (each gate with its own finite delay in real world), then the overall gate-delay can be modeled using this type of delay assignment.

Comment: Verilog questions are welcome here but when involving real world effects of voltage [http://electronics.stackexchange.com/](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Morgan Thank you for reminding me of that : )

Answer (score 1):

```
wire c;
assign #5 c = a && b; //delay in the continuous assignment

wire #5 c = a && b;   //delay in the implicit assignment

wire #5 c;  //delay in the wire declaration
assign c = a && b;
```

To demonstrate the pulse swallowing effect of the delays operator, consider the following scenario. In the above examples, if input a changed value at time 10 (and held its value for at least 5 time units), then the output c would change values at time 15. If input a had a value pulse that was shorter then the propagation delay of the assignment then the value on a would not be passed to the output.

In real world combinatorial logic has its own propagation delay, so it may occur that combo path may enough to not to pass transition shorter than its delay. See Image,

[image]

You can see, if launch flop has transition from 1-0-1 with Off period = 5ns, but net delay of combo path is 10ns then according to operating frequency (of course <10ns period of clk) it will not passed to Q of capturing flop. Timing comes when sequential circuit is there.  Combinational circuit doesn't have Clk, so it can operate at max depending on its load capacitance and parasitic component of CMOS (whatever the family).

Answer (score 1):

To cut in short, Look at the declaration of "w_tmp" in your code.

```
wire #20 w_tmp;
```

This declaration tells compiler that "w_tmp" is a wire, that has 20 time units of "inertial delay". 
[The pulse width less than inertial delay does not contain enough energy to switch output.](http://www.slideshare.net/jeetumistry28/delays-in-verilog)

Had it been "transport delay", You would have observed transitions at output as "a_i" changes it's states.